# Silverlight Binding Height to its parent element is not working

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datatemplate

```
<local:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="0"  Height="200"
                          IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="dgCaseHistory"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <local:CustomDataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  Background="Black" Height="{Binding ElementName=dgCaseHistory, Mode=TwoWay,Path=Height}">
                    <TextBlock Text="testestestest" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CustomDataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </local:CustomDataGrid>
```

Comment: You've set Mode as TwoWay, can you describe what you are expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) property.

```
<Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=dgCaseHistory, Mode=TwoWay, Path=ActualHeight}"> 
    <TextBlock Text="testestestest" /> 
</Grid>
```

If not, check the Output Window in Visual Studio for any DataBinding errors and update your question with those details.

Comment: I don't think you really want `Mode=TwoWay`